# Can't Connect to SQL Server if default port is not specified

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I've hit an odd situation with connecting to a SQL Server instance.  The instance is running and listening on port 1433 however I can't connect unless I specify the default port of 1433 in the connection string.

Does not work:

```
<add name="DataContext" connectionString="Data Source=192.168.150.1\sqlinstance;Initial Catalog=DATABASE;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=dbUser;Password=dbPass;MultipleActiveResultSets=True; Asynchronous Processing=true;Max Pool Size=700" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Does Work:

```
<add name="DataContext" connectionString="Data Source=192.168.150.1\sqlinstance,1433;Initial Catalog=DATABASE;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=dbUser;Password=dbPass;MultipleActiveResultSets=True; Asynchronous Processing=true;Max Pool Size=700" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

This only started happening recently and only affects our testing environment. Our production environment is configured identical except for the IP address and it does not suffer from this.  It's not a big deal to just add the port to the connection string but I'd like to figure out how this happened.  I should also mention I don't have issues when using Management Studio or just using telnet to verify the port is open.  I'm thinking this might be a C# or .net issue rather than a SQL Server configuration issue.

Comment: RE:  "... might be a C# or .net issue..."  .net is pretty narrow minded about things like fully declared connection strings.  I checked our SSIS connection strings and the port is explicitly declared. (I already had an environment open), so I cannot confirm the behavior you see.  But, c# / .net seems like a perfect cause.  You might want to anticipate a failure in production just to be safe.

Comment: To connect to named instances without specifying a port, the SQL Server Browser service is required -- it should be running, and port 1434 which it uses should be open for UDP traffic (on the server). This is true even if the named instance is running on the default port, since the connecting code can't assume that. Note that if you do specify a port, the name is ignored -- so 192.168.150.1,1433 will work just as well. The server not *having* a named instance would therefore also be a possible cause. The chance of this being a code issue (as in, the framework) is slim to none.

Answer (score 1):

set ms sql client protocols "shared memory" and "named pipes" as disable
if use only tcp ip - connection string without default port

Comment: Disabling the other options seems to have fixed the issue.  I can connect fine without specifying the port now.  Strange since they're enabled in production but that has no problem but glad it's working OK now.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I just needed to enable the service `SQL Server Browser`, it was disabled. 
Go to:

> SQL Server Configuration Manager > SQL Server Services > SQL Server Browser

Right click -> Properties 
Go to `Service` tab 
Start mode change to 'Automatic' or 'Manually' (whatever you decide) and voilà

Comment: It's disabled by default for security reasons.

Comment: The following may be of interest: [Connecting to SQL Server Instance without Browser running](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-technet-forums/edeab7bc-300d-4e19-8767-1c299970d841)